# Summing two boost::accumulator_set instances

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-accumulators

I have recently discovered the excellent library boost::accumulators, and I would like to use it to replace some of my code that accumulates statistics.

One thing I cannot find in the documentation is the ability to sum two accumulator sets, as in operator+=

Example:

```
using namespace boost::accumulators;
typedef accumulator_set<double, features<tag::variance> > AccumSet;

class Foo {
    AccumSet acc;
public:
    Foo& operator+=(const Foo& that) {
        this->acc += that.acc; // error! no such operator
        return *this;
    }
    double GetVariance() { return variance(acc); }
};
```

How can I achieve this using the available API? I don't know if this can be implemented for all the types of accumulators in the library (maybe not for tail), but it sure can be for important things, like count, sum, mean, moment, covariance, etc

Comment: You are also forgetting to `return *this;`, although this is unrelated.

Comment: @Matt, beside the point, but still worth fixing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not provided by Boost.Accumulators, probably because combining would only work for some statistics.

There is [a ticket on the Boost tracker](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2215) asking for such a `combine` function.

Comment: Thanks. I came to the same conclusion after looking around and posting in the boost mailing list. I was not aware of that ticket, though it was opened 4 years ago! My question is whether there's some workaround for the statistics that can be supported.

Comment: This situation is one typical usage where you may have several threads working together.  My own library provide this feature. This prevented me from switching to boost method.  acc1.merge(acc2), or acc1.absorb(acc2).  The operation should be simple enough (n1/(n1+n2))*avg1 + (n2/(n1+n2))*avg2) for mean.  variance can also be summed this way.  Note you don't want to use (n1*avg1 + n2*avg2)/(n1+n2), this way, you may get overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no appropriate and available  operator+= for adding two accumulator_set<> objects.